# Erro configuração Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuração

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este erro:

> Invalid NamespaceHandler class
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler]
>   for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]:
>   problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension

*ApplicationContext*:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.spring.JPA.Repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Olá! É um projeto novo ou fez alguma alteração recentemente nele que começou a ocasionar o erro?

Comment: Qual versão do `spring-data` da aplicação?

Comment: Versão 1.3 do spring-data projeto novo

Comment: Poderia informar as dependências desse projeto, com as versões?